# laravel 8 form validation stop working and throw an error

Tags: laravel, api, validation

here is my code for validate request

```
public function signup(Request $request) {
        
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|unique:users|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);

        $data = array();
        $data['name'] = $request->name;
        $data['email'] = $request->email;
        $data['password'] = Hash::make($request->password);
        
        DB::table('users')->insert($data);

        return $this->login($request);

    }
```

when I try this validation not working how can I fix this?

for example

when this data for validation

```
        'name' = "",(empty)
        'email' = "test2@mail.com"
        'password'= "test2@mail.com"
```

and I expect my validation should work but its throw BadMethodCallException error

here is my route (via API)

```
<?php

Route::group([

    'middleware' => 'api',
    'prefix' => 'auth'

], function ($router) {

    Route::post('login', [App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::class, 'login']);
    Route::post('logout', [App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::class, 'logout']);
    Route::post('refresh', [App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::class, 'refresh']);
    Route::post('me', [App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::class, 'me']);


    //custom
    Route::post('signup', [App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::class, 'signup']);

});
```

NOTE: am check this VIA postman

Comment: "not working" - What do you mean by that? Is it throwing an error? Please provide more details. Saying something is not working, but not saying why or how doesn't help us help you...

Comment: just show blanck  page

Comment: i modify my question thz

Comment: Please show your route and form who trigger this method

Comment: hi modify question

Comment: Did you call the route with the `POST` verb in Postman ? `BadMethodCallException` occur typically when the route call and the route verb declaration are not the same

Comment: yes i call in POST method

Comment: Please post the full url

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/signup  (with post method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it another way with the laravel `Validator` class. Please add `use Validator` class before your class declaration.

Then create your function like this:

```
public function signup(Request $request) {
    $validate = array(
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|unique:users|max:255',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
);
    $validatedData = Validator::make($request->all(),$validate);
    if(!validatedData->fails()) {
      return $validatedData->errors();
    }else{
    $data = array();
    $data['name'] = $request->name;
    $data['email'] = $request->email;
    $data['password'] = Hash::make($request->password);
    
    DB::table('users')->insert($data);

    return $this->login($request);
    }

    
}
```

Comment: I think you have to catch the validation error and return it in JSON format-

Comment: how can i check this with if ?